# Declaration of static array generates the following warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'v' [-Wvla]

Tags: c, warnings

The below code works just fine to save and print a static 5-component array. However, I am still getting a warning that I don't really know how to fix: `[Warning] ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'v' [-Wvla]`. It comes from where the vector is declared:  `float v[n];` Any help on this one would be very much appreciated. Thank you! :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_vector(int N, float * V);
void save_vector(int N, float * V);

int main(void)
{
    const int n = 5;
    float v[n];

    printf("Enter the %d components of the vector:\n", n);
    save_vector(n, v);

    puts("\nThe vector is:");
    print_vector(n, v);

    return 0;
}

void save_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%f", V+i);
}

void print_vector(int N, float * V)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf(" %.2f ", V[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no 'static array' in the code shown.  There is a variably-modified local array `v` in `main()`.

Comment: Yes, now I am starting to get the nuances on where to declare the variables. Thanks @JonathanLeffler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array:

```
float v[n];
```

Is considered a variable length array because the size of the array is not a compile time constant.  Variables declared `const` do not qualify as a compile time constant.

What you can do instead is use a preprocessor macro for the size

```
#define N 5
...
float v[N];
```

The preprocessor does direct token substitution, so `N` is a compile time constant in this case.

Comment: hey @dbush! very quick question: why did you use uppercase N? I mean, I am seeing frequently the use of Upper & Lowercase variables but not sure if there is a convention for this, or it is just dependant on personal preference? Thank you!

Comment: @Henry Macros typically use upper case to distinguish them from regular variables or functions.

Comment: All clear @dbush, thank you very much for all your help!! :-)